# Make subview rotate too when device is rotated iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, subview

Let me explain what I mean when I say that I want to rotate my subview too. I placed a lot of images to make my self clear. This may look like to much but it is not. Just wanted to be clear.

In the nib file that I am currently working on, I have a UIView and button.

[image]

The UIView that I created in interface builder is connected with the IBOutlet named ViewMain:

[image]

and the button executes the following method:
[image]

and what that method does is that it places the view from another nib file in the UIView controller that I created in interface builder. The nib file that I am actually placing is:

[image]

I just placed random controls to illustrate better my point.

so everything so far is great (the view from anotherViewController shows up on ViewMain when the user presses the button)

[image]

[image]

EVERYTHING LOOKS GREAT BUT NOTE WHAT HAPPENS WHEN I ROTATE MY DEVICE:

[image]

I would like my subview (anotherViewController.view) to ratate as well. I don't mind if it is bigger than ViewMain because I can have a transparent background. I just need to rotate it as well. How can I do that?

Comment: You want it to rotate?  Or do you want the the view to change it's dimension to match the new size?

Comment: to match the dimensions of the outer/root view... The same thing that happens when you rotate a UIView that does not have any subviews. I want it to behave like the uiview that has a white background. And resizing it may be a solution. I don't know how to do that though...

Comment: the reason this isn't rotating is because it's viewController isn't in the view controller hierarchy so isn't getting rotation notifications. its covered in wwdc session 102 or 104 if you have access to the videos (http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in you `UIViewController` so that it always returns YES:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
 {
    return YES;
 }
```

Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:) for more details.

You should also take care to correctly define the autoresizing behavior of your view and subviews, so that everything is fine when autorotating.

EDIT:

to set the autoresize property for a view in Interface Builder, select the view then go to the "View Size" pane in the Info window and set "Autosizing" as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: That method is in there by default and it still does not rotate... Plus that method is in all my .m files. Maybe I have to call that method from the root view when executing the code from the button.

Comment: Could you add one more picture with the layout you would like to obtain?

Comment: I don't know yet because I am planing to add several views depending on what button the user presses. But the last thing that you said sounds like a great idea. maybe I just have to re size it to the dimensions of the root uiview, the one that has white on the last picture that I posted sergio...

Comment: You can resize the view the setting the `view.frame` to a `CGRect` that suits you. But the way to do it is setting the view autoresizing property in IB... see my edited answer...