# Drag UIView without disabling its child controls iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, interface-builder, drag

I have a UIView control (white rectangle in image)

[image]

Moreover I am able to drag that control...

[image]

And when I press the button I load a subview which is another nib that I created and I placed random controls in it to illustrate my point...

[image]

If you guys are interested in finding out how I placed that nib file in that UIView control take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654741/make-subview-rotate-too-when-device-is-rotated-iphone-ipad) question. I don't thing you have to read it in order to understand my question.

Anyways the problem when loading that nib file is that I can no longer drag the top UIView. Because of this I changed:

[image]

for:

[image]

in the UIView of the subview. In otherwords the UIView of the nib file that I am placing in the UIView that has the white background.

and when I did that I was able to drag the control but the controls inside the subview no longer works. I have also tried placing the touchesMoved method in the subview instead but when I do that the application behaves strange. Plus the purpose of placing the nib file in a UIView control was to avoid repeating the same drag funcionality on several nib files.

I actually need to create an application like a power point presentation and I need to change the slide as the user slides the UIView and if it's cords are less than x for example then I load the next slide (nib file) in that uiview controller. Maybe there is a simpler way of doing what I need but if I get this drag to work I am done cause I would just have to do that functionality just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave the UserInteractionEnabled flag on for your subview if you want it to respond to events.

One way to achieve this would be to do your dragging using a UIGestureRecognizer.

**UIPanGestureRecognizer** is perfect for this ([UIGestureRecognizer at apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer))

Basically you'd attach the gesturerecognizer to the view which you want to pan then adjust it's position in the callbacks it provides.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[draggableSubview addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release];
```

Then in the handlePanGesture method you figure out how far the user panned using the translationInView method of the recognizer which it gets passed and translate the subview accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot that seems to be exactly what I need but I don't know how to use it. Where do I have to place the delegate? I am new to objective-c...